# Binary read data to float C++

Tags: c++, csv, binary

I need to read into my program some data from `.CSV` file and I have no idea how to change this number into float.
I can use only standard libraries and this file needs to be binary (`ios::binary`).

This is how it looks like in .csv file:

```
Lateral.Range(mm),5.000000
```

How to make this "5.000000" a float?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream obraz;
    obraz.open("File_name.csv", ios::binary);

    if(!obraz)
        cerr<<"nie udalo sie otworzyc pliku "<<endl;

    char lat_ran[18]; // text before the number
    float lateral_range;

    obraz.read(lat_ran, sizeof(lat_ran));
    obraz.read(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&lateral_range), sizeof(float)); // I know this part is wrong.

    obraz.close();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, your file is in text format and you read it as raw binary.

Comment: CSV is not a binary format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) operator:
`obraz >> lateral_range;`.

Comment: @Artur - You might as well accept this as the answer then. Now it stays on the list as 'unanswered'.

Comment: Oh, true. Thanks :) . I'm new here and I didn't realize that.